# C# Передача ValueMember из DataGridViewComboBoxColumn в таблицу БД как ID

Tags: c#

Добавляю столбец ProductComboBox в datagridview и подгружаю значения из таблицы d__Product. Все выводит правильно.

```
        string GetProduct = "select * from d__Product";
        DataTable dt = DbConnection.DBConnect(GetProduct);
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ProductComboBox = new 
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ProductComboBox.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        ProductComboBox.HeaderText = "Продукт";
        ProductComboBox.Name = "ProductComboBox";
        ProductComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        ProductComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
        ProductComboBox.DataPropertyName = "ID";
        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
        }
        ProductComboBox.Items.AddRange(row.ToArray());
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ProductComboBox);
```

Теперь мне необходимо отправлять данные из datagridview в таблицу БД.
При выборе данных их combobox у меня выводит только имена, а мне необходимо выводить ID (ValueMember). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?
Код отправки данных в таблицу БД, ниже. Отправка данных из Combobox происходит в строке dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string GetID = "select ID from d__RenderedServiceHead where NUM = '" 
        + GetStatus + "'";
        DataTable dt = DbConnection.DBConnect(GetID);
        string ID = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string FillBody = "insert into d__RenderedServiceBody values(" + 
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + ",'" + 
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + 
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + ID + 
            "',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";
            DbConnection.DBConnect(FillBody);
        }
    }
```

Comment: string ID = ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dt.Rows[0][0]).ValueMember ?

Comment: переменная ID не относится к combobox, я просто вывожу в ней ID документа.
combobox у меня находится в Cells[2] и Cells[3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ошибку в своем коде.
Через foreach я вывожу значения только Name, без ID в принципе.
Прописал так ProductComboBox.DataSource = dt;
теперь все правильно выходит.